# Acronis Backup & Recovery 10 - Failed to Recover Image

Tags: windows-7, acronis

I am having a problem loading my acronis image onto dissimilar hardware.

My image was created off a solid state drive, Windows 7 x64.
I am trying to load it onto a WD Raptor mechanical drive.
The imaging process went through ok, but when i try to boot into windows I get a blue screen and reboot.

Thanks for any suggestions.
dg

Comment: Is the only change the HDD?

Comment: I suspect the issue might be due to different storage controllers between the machines.  Please confirm.

Comment: Do you have Universal Restore add-on?  This helps strip the drivers so the image can be loaded on dissimilar hardware with ease.

Comment: no, i don't have this add-on, but i am looking into getting it.

Comment: the target machine is exactly the same, and the storage controller is identical but the SSD from which the image was made was using the "RAID ON" SATA operation mode in the BIOS, while the HDD in the target machine was using the "RAID Autodetect/ATA" SATA operation mode.

Comment: The only change between source and target machine is the HDD and the SATA mode in the BIOS

Comment: The problem went away after I switched the target machine to "RAID ON" SATA operation mode in the BIOS and re-imaged the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away after I switched the target machine to "RAID ON" SATA operation mode in the BIOS and re-imaged the HDD.